# DIV jumps when using .effect("shake")

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have create a DIV that I have centered and wish to use as a login screen. When validating the user input I wish to shake the DIV like when you try and login to a Mac. All is well however when the shack effect is called my login DIV is moved to a lower point on the screen as if it's doubling the left and top. When calling my shake effect I try to reposition the DIV to counter effect this repositioning but that all goes wrong... okay here's my HTML and CSS for the login screen:

HTML (the only other code in the page is BODY, LINK and SCRIPT tags):

```
<div id="login">
        <h1>Test Login Form</h1>
            <form action="" method="post" id="formlogin" >
                <div class="pdbt10">
                    <label for="j_username">Benutzername:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="j_username" id="j_username" />
                </div>

                <div class="pdbt10">
                    <label for="j_passwort">Passwort:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="j_passwort" id="j_passwort" />
                </div>

                <div id="errormessage" class="pdbt10"></div>

                <input type="submit" value="login" class="button" id="btnlogin" />
            </form>
    </div>
```

the CSS for this page:

```
label{
    padding-left:130px;
    width:105px;
    display:inline-block;
}

#btnlogin{
    margin-left:286px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

#errormessage{
    display:none;
}

#login{
    width:400px;
    position:absolute;
    left: 60%;
    top: 70%;
    margin-left: -25%;
    margin-top: -20%;
    padding:30px 30px 30px 30px;

    background-color:#e60000;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    color:#fff;
    overflow:visible;
}

.pdbt10{
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

and here's my JS/JQuery...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // let's start...

    // clear warning in case is block
    $("#j_username").focus(function(){
        $("#errormessage").css("display","none");
    });

// validate form on submit...
   $("#formlogin").submit(function(){

       var userName = $("#j_username").val();
       var passWord = $("#j_passwort").val(); 

       if(userName == "" && passWord != ""){
            $("#errormessage").css("display","block");
            $("#errormessage").html("Error 1");
            shakeTheRoom();
       }else if(userName != "" && passWord == ""){
            $("#errormessage").css("display","block");
            $("#errormessage").html("Error2");     
            shakeTheRoom();
       }else if(userName == "" && passWord == ""){
            $("#errormessage").css("display","block");
            $("#errormessage").html("Error3.");    
            shakeTheRoom();
       }
       return false;
   });
});


function shakeTheRoom(){
    $('#login').effect("shake", { distance:100,times:2 }, 100);
}
```

Here's the code on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/itakesmack/AvPYa/1/

Any help and advice would be appreciated

Comment: I#ve added a wrapper DIV around the Form and given this the following CSS: { position:absolute;
 left: 60%;
 top: 70%;
 margin-left: -25%;
 margin-top: -20%}

that seems to work...

Answer (score 4):

What the jQuery shake function actually does to you're code is puts the

```
<div id="login"></div>
```

into it's own wrapper with all the style of that login div as an inline style. what it's actually missing is your margin-top: -20%.

```
font-size: 100%; background-image: initial; 
background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; 
background-clip: initial; background-color: transparent; 
border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; 
border-bottom-style: none; border-left-style: none; 
border-top-width: initial; border-right-width: initial; 
border-bottom-width: initial; border-left-width: initial; 
border-top-color: initial; border-right-color: initial; 
border-bottom-color: initial; border-left-color: initial; 
border-image: initial; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; 
margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; 
padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; 
width: 327px; height: 162px; float: none; position: absolute; 
z-index: auto; top: 70%; left: 60%; bottom: auto; right: auto; 
background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;
```

Thats what it gives the new wrapper hence the jump. As you know the height of the box and width you're best using the following http://jsfiddle.net/AvPYa/4/

What I've done here is sat it in the middle of the page then taken away half the height and width of the box to make it sit central. Also it removes this jump :)

Answer (score 1):

In the CSS for #login, change your margin so that it doesn't use a percentage, e.g.

```
margin-top: -100px;
```